# Bing Maps in an MVC2 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, dictionary, bing

I'm trying to find the best way to implement Bing maps into my ASP.NET MVC2 web application.

I came accross [MvcMaps Preview1](http://mvcmaps.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex but it doesn't work good, at least for me. Maybe that's because it's for .NET 3.5 and VS2008, I don't know.

I'd like to avoid Silverlight. What's your suggestion, what should I use and what's the easiest way to get a Bing Map show some data on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [NerdDinner Tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm). Part of the tutorial is the [integration of maps](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part11.htm) within your web application.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an MVC mapping application (all be it in PHP) and used OpenLayers for mapping. It's a client side Javascript library for mapping.

http://openlayers.org/